# spring websocket notification

Tags: spring, websocket

Ok here i'm , i'm right now following the guides on spring site but i'm having problem on how to deliver a notification to only one user using WebSocket, i'm following this guide https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/ .
What I want is: i have 2 users, both of them subscribe to process1... User1 need to let the server process his pass...now i want that the server will deliver the notification only to User1...

```
@Controller
public class ProcessController {
   @MessageMapping("/ProcessOwner/approve/{pass}")
   @SendTo("")
   public String notifica(@DestinationVariable String pass)throws Exception{
      return "ok"+pass;
   }
}
```

Now what should i write in the @SendTo field to deliver the answer only to user1 ? if ill write /Process/process1 both user1 and user2 will receive the message....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ca use the sufix. It's send to every unique client.

When you subscribe in the js code:

```
client.connect('guest', 'guest', function(frame) {

  var suffix = frame.headers['queue-suffix'];

  client.subscribe("/queue/error" + suffix, function(msg) {
    // handle error
  });

  client.subscribe("/queue/position-updates" + suffix, function(msg) {
    // handle position update
  });

});
```

On the server side you can use `@ReplyToUser` or the message template

```
String user = "fabrice";
String queue = "/queue/position-updates";
this.messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(user, queue, position);
```

See more here: http://assets.spring.io/wp/WebSocketBlogPost.html (section: Sending Messages To a Single User)

Comment: I finded it but I have some problem understanding it... How do I know that the user is "fabrice"?
this.messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(user, queue, position); //this line sent to user fabrice that is subscribed to /queue/position-updates but how do it knows that it's the previous client you mentioned?

Comment: Take a look here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html (section 20.4.9 Authentication)

Comment: It seems this behavior has changed in more recent spring version, spring manages queues and suffixes on server-side, and does not expose to clients. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26991832