# Spring WebSocket is not send queue-suffix after connection

Tags: stomp, spring-websocket

My server side config is here:

```
<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/chat">
        <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/connect">
          <websocket:sockjs/>
        </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
        <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/broadcast/"/>
</websocket:message-broker>
```

Client side code:

```
var stompClient = null;
var socket = new SockJS('/connect');
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient.connect('', '', function (frame) {
    console.log(frame); // Inside frame object queue-suffix not sended
    var suffix = frame.headers['queue-suffix'];
    stompClient.subscribe('/broadcast/message'+suffix, function(calResult){
      console.log(calResult);
    });
}, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Connection is successfully, but I can't find queue-suffix in connection frame object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the annotation-based configs and messaging classes. I'm also using SpringBoot 1.2.0.RC1 which pulls in Spring 4.1.2.RELEASE.

So, given that I set up my websockets & STOMP as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketProdConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {
       stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/inoutboard").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
       registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
       registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
    }
 }
```

and then an example of a send/receive method in my controller is

```
@Controller
public class InOutBoardController {
...
    @MessageMapping("/user-status-refresh")
    @SendToUser(value = "/queue/user-status-refresh", broadcast = false)
    public UserStatusUpdateMessage[] userStatusRefresh() {
        ...
    }
}
```

When I get my messages in the client, they have a topic of "/user/njacobs5074/queue/user-status-values".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

We did include such a header in early milestones (up until 4.0 RC1 I think) but the "queue suffix" is now completed encapsulated on the server side. See the example from Nick above and also the docs [Spring WebSocket is not send queue-suffix after connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26991832/spring-websocket-is-not-send-queue-suffix-after-connection).